# JAVA String Reverse using StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

This code always returns false. What might be the problem ?

```
  public class S18_Palindrome {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = new String("malayalam");
        if (myString.equals(new StringBuilder(myString).reverse())) {
          System.out.println("true");
        } else {
          System.out.println("false");
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `StringBuilder(myString).reverse()` will return a `StringBuilder` object you need to get the string value out of it.

```
new StringBuilder(myString).reverse().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it :)

I had to convert the StringBuilder's value toString()

```
if (myString.equals(new StringBuilder(myString).reverse().toString()))
```

instead of

```
if (myString.equals(new StringBuilder(myString).reverse()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
String s = "responses";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);
System.out.println(builder.reverse());
```

Comment: it is just example of check reverse string.

Comment: But he asked why `myString.equals(new StringBuilder(myString).reverse())` always returns false..